# Moving an Linux OS image from a 4 GB flash drive to a hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-disk, dd, disk-image, flash-memory

I have a small flash drive (4 GB) that has a stripped down version of Redhat Linux. I'm currently attempting to move this OS from the flash drive to a much bigger hard drive (500 GB) that is bootable. I was able to copy the image from the flash drive to my computer, but am having issues when copying it to the hard drive.

I'm trying to use [dd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) but it seems that when copying over the image to the hard drive, the image only has access to 4 GB of memory (what it was allocated from the flash drive). The other 496 GB on the hard drive become completely unusable. This obviously defeats the purpose. We'd like to expand the partition but once the OS is `dd` over to the hard drive it seems that the 496 GB are unavailable.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your partition table from the 4GB USB stick uses only 4GB. In order to increase thisyou have to increase

- the size of the partition
- the size of the file system.

Parted can resize some file systems.

The other option is to manually create a partition and a file system and copy the files.

Comment: Hi @RalfFriedl thanks for he information. The issues seems to be that we're moving the memory from the USB to the Hard Drive, then the hard drive seems to be only 4 GB as well. The OS doesn't seem to notice the other 496 GBs. How can I add this? What tools would you recommend?

Comment: I already explained that the reason the OS doesn't recognize the rest is because of the size of the partition table, and I already recommended parted.